# Building an Android app with Kivy+Buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I have Python 3.7 and Windows 7 x64, and I did:

```
pip install kivy buildozer
```

It works, and I can successfully run a hello world example on my Windows machine:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='hello world')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Then I created a buildozer file with:

```
buildozer init
```

and modifier the .spec file to use the right `main.py`.

But then:

```
buildozer android debug
```

fails:

> Unknown command/target android

**How to compile an APK with Kivy + Buildozer on Windows?**

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), "You must have a Linux or OSX computer to be able to compile for Android". You can try using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

- Android: via Python for Android. You must have a Linux or OSX computer to be able to compile for Android.
- iOS: via Kivy iOS. You must have an OSX computer to be able to compile for iOS.
- Supporting others platform is in the roadmap (such as .exe for Windows, .dmg for OSX, etc.)

So, `Windows` is in the roadmap, but who knows when that might happen. Until then, you can use something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to run `Linux` on your `Windows` machine and run `buildozer` there.

Answer (score 0):

This guide helped me - https://blog.kivy.org/2019/05/running-buildozer-in-a-virtual-machine/
You might need to install some linux dependencies before running buildozer, if you follow this guide.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to John's answer - there is one other way to do this using Google Colab! In my experience this has been quite a convenient way to generate apk files.

To achieve this, create a new Google Colab File. Upload your required files to the Colab space (These files will not be saved in the long run!). Then follow the next steps:

In Google Colab install buildozer, cython and other requirements using the following code:

```
!pip install buildozer
!pip install cython==0.29.21
!sudo apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev\
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
!sudo apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6

!sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
!buildozer init
```

Now a buildozer.spec file will be generated, you can adjust this to all your needs. This generally has plenty of documentation online, so I assume this is known.

Then in the colab file run

```
!buildozer -v android debug
```

Lastly followed by

```
!buildozer android clean
```

To generate an APK file that is usable.

This has worked quite successfully for me to generate android APK files.

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af)